# Is there way to communicate with samba server using SAMR protocol from java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, samba, jcifs, ms-samr

I start Samba server using following docker-compose:

```
services:
  samba:
    image: instantlinux/samba-dc:latest
    container_name: samba-dc
    cap_add:
      - CAP_SYS_ADMIN
    hostname: my.company
    environment:
      DOMAIN_ACTION: provision
      REALM: my.company
    volumes:
      - etc:/etc/samba
      - lib:/var/lib/samba
    ports:
      - "53:53"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "88:88"
      - "88:88/udp"
      - "389:389"
      - "139:139"
      - "446:445"
    secrets:
      - samba-admin-password
```

I want to integrate my spring application with samba server using [SAMR protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-samr/4df07fab-1bbc-452f-8e92-7853a3c7e380)

I can't find any example/library in network. Is there any library for that ?

### Update

I've found [jcif library](https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs) and it even contains classes related to SAMR protocol but I have no idea how to use it.

- https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs/blob/master/src/main/java/jcifs/dcerpc/msrpc/MsrpcSamrConnect2.java
- https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs/blob/master/src/main/java/jcifs/dcerpc/msrpc/MsrpcSamrConnect4.java
- https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs/blob/master/src/main/java/jcifs/dcerpc/msrpc/samr.java
- ...

I want to get working example ([MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Could you please help ?

Comment: Downvoters please explain your votes. I am ready to enrich the question with details but I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: You can see the closure reason attached to the two existing closevotes on your answer: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more / This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers." - this *is*, essentially, a question seeking recommendation for a library.

Comment: @nanofarad I am looking for any working tool. Absolutely any. I can't find any working solution. I don't understand if there are no of them or I am a bad searcher.

Comment: I didn't see any when I searched either, aside from https://github.com/rapid7/smbj-rpc/tree/master/src/main/java/com/rapid7/client/dcerpc/mssamr, and I don't have enough background to evaluate whether it's a good fit for you. You may very well need to get the protocol spec and implement your own library based on the spec if you can't find something

Comment: thank you for your effort. I will investigate. Regarding the suggestion to implement library by my own - I have no idea where to start from. I didn't have such experience

Comment: Looking at the protocol [spec](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-SAMR/%5bMS-SAMR%5d.pdf), it does look quite complex unfortunately, even the starting points. You might be able to use libraries for lower-level components of the protocol, like the NDR format that the messages are sent in. If you could implement only the interactions you need for your program, that could save a lot of time, both for development and for investigation/testing.

Comment: I would appreciate if you show me at least a single interaction

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
// SambaService.java
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

public interface SambaService extends Library {
    SambaService INSTANCE = Native.load("samba", SambaService.class);

    int samrConnect(String serverName, String domainName, String username, String password);

    void samrDisconnect(int connectionHandle);

    int samrCreateUser2(int connectionHandle, String userName, int userAccountControl, SamrUserAllInfo userInfo,
                       IntByReference userId);

    class SamrUserAllInfo extends Structure {
        // Define the structure fields based on the SAMR_USER_ALL_INFORMATION structure in the SAMR library
        // You'll need to match the structure fields with the actual structure in the library

        public static class ByReference extends SamrUserAllInfo implements Structure.ByReference {
        }

        // Define the constructor and field mappings based on the structure
        // For example:
        public int accountControl;
        public int unknownField;
    }
}
```

And if you want to use the above class

```
        int connectionHandle = SambaService.INSTANCE.samrConnect("sambaServer", "domain", "username", "password");

        SambaService.SamrUserAllInfo userInfo = new SambaService.SamrUserAllInfo();
        userInfo.accountControl = request.getAccountControl(); // Set the desired user account control flags

        IntByReference userId = new IntByReference();
        int result = SambaService.INSTANCE.samrCreateUser2(connectionHandle, request.getUserName(),
                request.getAccountControl(), userInfo, userId);

        SambaService.INSTANCE.samrDisconnect(connectionHandle);

        if (result == 0) {
            return "User created successfully. User ID: " + userId.getValue();
        } else {
            return "Failed to create user.";
        }
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure it is an updated version.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but could you explain this line ?  Native.load("samba", SambaService.class);

Comment: Could you please fill in the gaps in your example.

I don't know how to fill in the structure and constructor.

`request` variable  is also not defined.